# Time and Space Complexity of This Algorithm

Tags: complexity-theory, analysis

Despite reading some previous questions here on stackoverflow and watching a few videos including [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8syQKTdgdzc)
one, time and space complexity are going straight over my head. I need to find the time and space complexity of this algorithm

```
public static int aPowB(int a, int b){
        if(b == 0){
            return 1;
        }
        int halfResult = aPowB(a, b/2);
        if(b%2 == 0){
            return halfResult * halfResult;
        }
        return a * halfResult * halfResult;
    }
```

An explanation of the answer would be appreciated so I can try to understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the inputs are `a` and `b`, so we can expect the time/space complexity to be dependent on this two parameters.

With recursive algorithms, always try to write down the recurrence relation for the time complexity `T` first. Here it's

```
T(a, 0) = O(1)              // base case
T(a, b) = T(a, b/2) + O(1)  // recursive call + some O(1) stuff at the end
```

This equation is one of the standard ones that you should just know by heart, so we can immediately give the solution

```
T(a, b) = O(log b)
```

(If you don't know the solution by hard, just ask yourself how many times you can divide `b` by 2 until you hit 0.)

The space complexity is also `O(log b)` because that's the depth of the recursion stack.